# ms web plugin - navigate to another html in the same plugin container

Tags: ms-office, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I started a new MS outlook plugin as described in their advanced tutorial. Now I want to add framework7 library. I installed via npm and referenced it correctly. So my starting html now correctly loads the framework.

Now I want to define routes to other html pages that will replace the current one as it is by framework7 policy, but I can not find a way to navigate to another page in the outlook plugin. Is this even possible?

Example from plugin index.html:

```
...
<a href="/about/">About app</a>
...
```

and in index.js

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    var app = new Framework7({
        root: '#app',
        name: 'My App',
        id: 'com.myapp.test',
        panel: {
            swipe: 'left',
        },
        routes: [
        {
            path: '/about/',
            url: 'about.html',
        }
    ]
});
```

Is it possible to navigate to another html in the same plugin container?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to navigate to another html in the same plugin container, as long as the domain is part of your AppDomain collection in the manifest. The code you have above does not invoke any outlook-addin API. Are you clicking on a link that is not navigating to the about.html file? Are you calling mainView.router.navigate or some other Framework7 API that is not working?

Comment: Thank you, for your message. I'll give some more details above, as I found part of the problems but still can't make it work.

Comment: Each page must load a script that leverages Office.initialize in order to use the Office.js APIs.